# How do I re-render dynamically generated anchor tags in jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, widget, refresh

I get an anchor tag snippet html from the server on ajax call. How do I "refresh" so that jquery mobile can append the necessary classes to the links?

For example the link that jquery mobile generates has a ui-link:

```
<a class="ui-link" href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

How do I ensure that the correct styles are appended on a newly generated anchor tag?

Comment: Run a function as part of the `success` callback for the Ajax call?

Comment: Can you post your JS code? What widgets specifically are you trying to `refresh`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh a widget that has already been initialized then you can refresh each type of widget using it's respective function:

```
$('.ui-btn').button('refresh');
```

Notice I used the `.ui-btn` class to select the button elements, this class is added once the button is initialized, so you can be sure that you are refreshing an already initialized button widget.

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/buttons/buttons-methods.html

If you need to initialize a widget that has yet to be initialized, then you just omit the `'refresh'` or use `.trigger('create')`:

```
$('[data-role="button"], button, input[type="button"], input[type="submit"]').not('.ui-btn').button();//or .trigger('create');
```

Notice here I omit the already initialized widgets by using `.not('.ui-btn')` so this will only initialize un-initialized widgets. If you try to initialize a widget that has already been initialized then you get an error (same if you try to refresh a widget that hasn't been initialized yet).

## Update

If your HTML is being outputted by the server then you can initialize the widgets before adding them to the DOM:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success : function (serverResponse) {
        var $out = $(serverResponse);
        //if there is a container with elements inside it, use `.find()`,
        //if all the elements are siblings at the top level then use `.filter()`
        $out.find('a').button();
        $('body').append($out);
    }
});
```

You can also use the `.buttonMarkup()` function to update button widgets: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is at least one way to refresh styling for jQuery Mobile buttons:

```
$(yourButtons).button('refresh');
```

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html